# How to use Gtk.events_pending?

Tags: python, gtk3

I've got this basic "test" application, in which I would like to display a spinner while it is doing its long **launching** process (functions with database requests) to let the user know that it is not bugging but launching. I've read in other posts that it is possible to do this with `Gtk.events_pending()` function but I don't know how/where to use it.
I've tried many ways, but the main window always displays only when requests are done :

Here is the main .py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: Utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf, GObject

import Mng,os.path

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# MAIN WINDOW ######################################################################################
class PyApp:
    def __init__(self):
        builder = Gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file(path + "/test.glade")
        self.obj = builder.get_object

        """
        I would like to display on main window a
        spinner while doing requests. There is a
        self.obj('spinner') in main window,
        in glade file to do so.
        """ 
        self.do_requests()

        self.obj('main').show_all()

    def do_requests(self):
        mng = Mng.Grab([
            [1,'getPlayers'],
            [2,'getFactions'],
            [3,'getBoards']
        ])
        data = mng.grab_data()
        players, nb = data[1]
        factions, nb = data[2]
        boards, nb = data[3]

        """
         Here will be the code to display data in GUI,
         like for example : self.obj('label_players').set_text(str(players))
        """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = PyApp()
    Gtk.main()
```

Here is the Mng.py file in which I will manage all my requests within a class  (I don't know if it is well coded because I just discovered multiple threading. But it does the trick):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: Utf-8 -*-
import os.path, DB
import concurrent.futures

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class Grab:    
    """
    Retrieves multiple database requests datas
    & returns results in a dict : {name of request: [result, lenght of result]}
    """
    def __init__(self, req_list):
        self.req_list = req_list

    def grab_data(self):

        def do_req(var, funct_name, args):
            if None in args:
                funct = getattr(self, str(funct_name))()
            else:
                #print("function",name,"*args : ", *args)
                funct = getattr(self, str(funct_name))(*args)
            res = [var, funct]
            return res

        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
            res_list = {}
            future_to_req = {executor.submit(do_req, req[0], req[1], req[2:]): req for req in self.req_list}
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_req):
                req = future_to_req[future]
                try:
                    data = future.result()
                except Exception as exc:
                    print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (req, exc))
                else:
                    res_list[data[0]] = data[1]

        return res_list

    def getFactions(self, ext1=False):
        req = DB.DB('SELECT * FROM factions')
        res = req.res
        nb = len(res)
        return res, nb

    def getBoards(self, ext1=False):
        req = DB.DB('SELECT * FROM boards')
        res = req.res
        nb = len(res)
        return res, nb


    def getPlayers(self):
        req = DB.DB('SELECT * FROM players')
        res = req.res
        nb = len(res)
        return res, nb
```

And the DB.py file doing requests:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: Utf-8 -*-

import mysql.connector as sql

class DB(object):    
    """DB initializes and manipulates MySQL databases."""

    def __init__(self, query):
        """Initialize a new or connect to an existing database.
        Accept setup statements to be executed.
        """
        self.database = '******'
        self.host = '**********'
        self.port = '********'
        self.user = '******'
        self.password = '***********'
        self.connect()
        self.execute(query)
        self.close()            

    def connect(self):
        """Connect to the MySQL database."""

        self.connection = sql.connect(host=self.host,port=self.port,user=self.user,password=self.password, database=self.database)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.connected = True

    def close(self): 
        """Close the MySQL database."""

        self.connection.close()
        self.connected = False

    def execute(self, query):
        """Execute complete SQL statements. """
        res = close = False
        if not self.connected:
            self.connect()
            close = True

        try:
            self.cursor.execute(query)
            if query.upper().startswith('SELECT'):
                res = self.cursor.fetchall()

        except sql.Error as e:
            try:
                print ("MySQL Error [%d]: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1]))
            except IndexError:
                print ("MySQL Error: %s" % str(e))

        if close:
            self.close()   

        self.res = res
```

Could you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I don't see any database requests happening in this code. How are you launching those? In a different thread?

Comment: I simulated them with time.sleep() function because this is not the important part of the question.

Comment: So the database requests happen in the same thread?

Comment: Well, the requests are done while app is launching in order to display data in main window once it is opened. What I would like to do is not wait for requests to be done to display main window.

Comment: Do you mean by "same thread" that I shouldn't include the do_requests() function in my App class?

Comment: Yes, that is what @Aran-Fey is suggesting. You could use threading to launch your database requests, but beware that some database queries have special threading caveats. A more complete code example would really help here.

Comment: Also read up on multithreading.

Comment: Ok, sorry if I was not clear. I've edited my question with more details. Yes, @theGtknerd, I've also tried to reduce requests time process with multithreading, as you can see in the edited post. It makes requests time shorter but this is not really the goal here.

Comment: But this is a nice idea because in the initial code, there are lots of other requests. But in order to simplify code here I've removed them.

Comment: @Feign' Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52450529/use-gtk-events-pending-to-show-a-loading-gtktreeview/52450530#52450530) using events_pending. It can't be used for what you need (querying databases), but since you asked :)

Comment: @theGtknerd I tested your events_pending example. Thanks for it. So -tell me if I'm wrong- events_pending forces UI to update during loop. Now it's time for me to integrate all that in my code... ... ...! :)

Comment: You are right and you are quite welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you understand how multiprocessing is supposed to work. Sorry, but I can't give you a full demo with your code built in, but hopefully you can figure it out.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib, Gdk
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
from queue import Empty
import os, sys, time

UI_FILE = "src/pygtk_foobar.ui"

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):

        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(UI_FILE)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        self.window1 = self.builder.get_object('window1')
        self.window1.show_all()
        self.builder.get_object('spin1').start()

        self.data_queue = Queue()
        thread = Process(target=self.thread_start)
        thread.start()

        GLib.timeout_add(100, self.get_result )

    def thread_start (self):
        time.sleep(5)
        self.data_queue.put("done")

    def get_result (self):
        try:
            result = self.data_queue.get_nowait()
            print (result)
            self.builder.get_object('spin1').stop()
        except Empty:
            return True

    def on_window_destroy(self, window):
        Gtk.main_quit()

def main():
    app = GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

**EDIT**

An explanation: GLib.timeout_add() will keep on polling as long as `get result` returns True. When the timeout gets returned None or False, it will quit polling. `get result` will try to get results from the data_queue, but if nothing is found, it will return True.

In your case, you would open the database requests with `def thread_start` and check the queue with `def get_result` until the info has been loaded. So multiprocessing will load the db info in one thread, while Gtk can do its window drawing in another thread, while periodically checking if the multiprocessing db thread is finished. When it is finished loading, cancel the timeout by not returning True, and do your thing with the db data.

I use this a lot to populate scanners, for example, while the user can operate the GUI.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @theGtknerd. I'll test it and see how I can integrate it in my code. I'll be back once done. :)

Comment: I understand better now what Aran-Fey meant by "same thread" but I'm still a bit confused with the meaning of the six last lines of your code, @theGtknerd, and don't understand the "GLib.timeout_add(100, self.get_result )" function's aim. I understand that it adds time between thread functions... is that right? Would you please explain what is it for?

Comment: @Feign' See my explanation.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help and explanations. It's more clear now, even if I need more practise to be comfortable with threads. :D  I'll choose your answer as the solution because it solved my problem and the result is what I wanted to see, even if it is not with Gtk.events_pending(). Thanks a lot!