# How can I update a section of a GTK+ GUI in a separate thread, which continuously reads data from another process?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gtk, gtk3

I have a problem while coding a GTK+ GUI to manage other processes, under Linux. I'm definitely not an expert with GTK+, and I can't seem to solve this problem.

I'm trying to write a GTK+ application which should run other processes (in particular, an iPerf - a network measurement program - client and an iPerf server, which are managed using `system()` and `popen()`/`pclose()`, depending on the buttons which are clicked by the users.

There are some buttons related to launching a client and two buttons to start and stop a server, which call their respective callbacks.

The server start button, in particular, calls a callback which is responsible for starting a thread, which should read data from the server (quite asynchronously) and update a section of the GUI accordingly, while the GUI should be responsive to perform other operations (e.g. start a client).

In particular, iPerf is set to output new data every 1s, and each data lies on each line returned by iPerf, every second.

I tried reading the data from the server using `popen()`.

If I launch the `serverParserIdle()` function (reported below), from within the GTK+ callback, using `gdk_threads_add_idle()`, it works, but with two big problems preventing the program from working properly:

1) iPerf output is buffered by `popen()` and the data is not parsed in real-time, as the program should do

2) The `serverParserIdle()` thread locks the GUI, and I cannot do other operations at the same time, such as running a client, which is something I need to do

Trying to solve (2), I tried changing with `gdk_threads_add_idle()` with `gdk_threads_add_timeout(1000,...)`. In this case the GUI is no more locked, but `popen` is returning `0` and the server is not launched. Do you know why?

What can I do to solve all the problems listed above?

This is the `serverParserIdle()` function mentioned before:

```
static gboolean serverParserIdle(gpointer data) {
    FILE *iperfFp;
    char linebuf[STRSIZE_LINEBUF];
    double goodput, final_goodput;
    char unit_letter;
    int total_datagrams, prev_total_datagrams=-1;
    struct parser_data *parser_data_struct=data;
    gchar *gput_label_str=NULL, *final_gput_label_str=NULL;
    char first_char;


    iperfFp=popen(parser_data_struct->cmd,"r"); //parser_data_struct->cmd contains a string containing the command to launch the iperf server "iperf -s -u -i 1 ..."

    if(!iperfFp) {
        // We enter here if gdk_threads_add_timeout(1000,...) is used to call serverParserIdle()
        return FALSE;
    }

    while(fgets(linebuf,sizeof(linebuf),iperfFp)!=NULL) {
        sscanf(linebuf,"%c %*s %*s %*f %*s %*f %*s %lf %c%*s %*f %*s %*s %d %*s",&first_char,&goodput,&unit_letter,&total_datagrams); // Parse useful data on this line

        if(first_char!='[' || (unit_letter!='K' && unit_letter!='M')) {
            // This is just to discrimate the useful lines
            continue;
        }

        if(unit_letter=='K') {
            goodput=goodput/1000;
        }

        // This is again a way to distinguish the last line of a client-server session from all the other lines
        if(prev_total_datagrams!=-1 && total_datagrams>prev_total_datagrams*2) {
            if(final_gput_label_str) {
                g_free(final_gput_label_str);
            }
            // Update final goodput value in the GUI
            final_goodput=goodput;
            prev_total_datagrams=-1;
            final_gput_label_str=g_strdup_printf("<b><span font=\"70\" foreground=\"blue\">%.2f</span></b>",goodput);
            gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(parser_data_struct->gput_labels.final_gput_info_label),final_gput_label_str);
        } else {
            if(gput_label_str) {
                g_free(gput_label_str);
            }
            prev_total_datagrams=total_datagrams;

            // Update current goodput value in the GUI (every 1s only when a client is being connected to the server)
            gput_label_str=g_strdup_printf("<b><span font=\"70\" foreground=\"#018729\">%.2f</span></b>",goodput);
            gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(parser_data_struct->gput_labels.gput_info_label),gput_label_str);
        }

        //fflush(iperfFp); <- tried flushing, but it does not work
    }

    pclose(iperfFp);

    g_free(gput_label_str);
    g_free(final_gput_label_str);


    return FALSE;
}
```

`gdk_threads_add_idle()` or `gdk_threads_add_timeout()` are actually called from a callback (`start_server()`), which is assigned to a button in `main()` using:

```
g_signal_connect(button,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(start_server),&(data));
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Would [Glib::IOChannel on pipe from popen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52480019/1981374) work for you?

Comment: To make it clear: do you understand that `gdk_threads_add_idle` doesn't launch any additional threads and it's function is executed in main thread?

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev Yes. In reality, that was something I was not completely sure about, but now it is clear. Thank you!

Comment: @pan-mroku Using IO Channels with `popen` actually solved my problem. I followed the documentation at the [GLib reference manual pages](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html), together with the suggestions from the answer you linked me and I was able to asynchronously update the GUI as the external process provided new data. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve data from blocking read in another thread in Gtk3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436541/how-to-retrieve-data-from-blocking-read-in-another-thread-in-gtk3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by following *pan-mroku*'s suggestion, i.e. by using [IO Channels on a pipe opened with popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436541/how-to-retrieve-data-from-blocking-read-in-another-thread-in-gtk3/52480019#52480019).

This is the relevant code which is, in the end, able to read information from the server as new lines, with new data, are printed to *stdout* by the server itself, and update the GTK+ GUI accordingly.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <errno.h>
// ...


static gboolean serverParser(GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition condition, gpointer data) {
    gchar *linebuf; gsize strsize_linebuf;
    GIOStatus opstatus;
    int scan_retval=0;
    // ...

    opstatus=g_io_channel_read_line(source,&linebuf,&strsize_linebuf,NULL,NULL);
    if(opstatus==G_IO_STATUS_NORMAL && strsize_linebuf!=0) {
        scan_retval=sscanf(linebuf,"%c %*s %f%*[- *]%f %*s %*f %*s %lf %c%*s %*f %*s %*f%*[/ *]%d %*s",&field_1,&field_2,&field_3,&field_4,&field_5,&field_6);

        if(scan_retval==6) {
            // Work with the parsed server data, line by line
        }
    }

    // ...

    g_free(linebuf);
    return TRUE;
}



static void start_server(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    // ...
    FILE *iperfFp;
    int iperfFd;
    GIOChannel *iperfIOchannel;

    // ...
    // Start server using stdbuf to get a line buffered output
    iperfFp=popen("stdbuf -o L iperf -s -u","r");

    if(!iperfFp) {
        g_print("Error in launching the server. errno = %d\n",errno);
        return;
    }

    iperfFd=fileno(iperfFp);

    iperfIOchannel=g_io_channel_unix_new(iperfFd);
    g_io_channel_set_flags(iperfIOchannel,G_IO_FLAG_NONBLOCK,NULL);
    g_io_channel_set_line_term(iperfIOchannel,NULL,-1);
    g_io_add_watch(iperfIOchannel,G_IO_IN,serverParser,&(data_struct->parser_pointers));

    // ...
}

// ...
```

When the start button is clicked, the `start_server` callback is invoked, which starts the iPerf server (but the same could be done for any other external process) with `popen` and configures a new IO Channel. Then, every time a new line is generated by the server itself, `serverParser` is called to parse all the relevant data.

I had to start the external iPerf process by invoking `stdbuf` first (with the argument `-o L`), in order to get a line buffered output and have `serverParser` called for each line generated by that process.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in Perl in case someone should be interested. This just shows the basic principle of how to do asynchronous things within the GTK event loop:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Glib 'TRUE', 'FALSE';
use Gtk3 -init;
use AnyEvent;  # Important: load AnyEvent after Glib!
use AnyEvent::Subprocess;

use constant {
    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER => 800,
};

my $window = Gtk3::Window->new( 'toplevel' );
my $grid1 = Gtk3::Grid->new();
$window->add( $grid1 );
my $frame1 = Gtk3::Frame->new('Output');
$frame1->set_size_request(800,600);
$grid1->attach($frame1, 0,0,1,1);
my $scrolled_window = Gtk3::ScrolledWindow->new();
$scrolled_window->set_border_width(5);
$scrolled_window->set_policy('automatic','automatic');
my $textview = Gtk3::TextView->new();
my $buffer = $textview->get_buffer();
$buffer->set_text ("Hello, this is some text\nHello world\n");
$textview->set_wrap_mode('none');
$textview->set_editable(FALSE);
$textview->set_cursor_visible(FALSE);
set_widget_property( $textview, 'font-size', '18px' );
my $bg_color = Gtk3::Gdk::RGBA::parse( "#411934" );
$textview->override_background_color('normal', $bg_color);
my $color = Gtk3::Gdk::RGBA::parse( "#e9e5e8" );
$textview->override_color('normal', $color);
$textview->set_monospace(TRUE);

$scrolled_window->add($textview);
$frame1->add($scrolled_window);
$window->set_border_width(5);
$window->set_default_size( 600, 400 );
$window->set_position('center_always');
$window->show_all();
setup_background_command( $buffer );  # start background command
my $condvar = AnyEvent->condvar;
$window->signal_connect( destroy  => sub { $condvar->send } );
my $done = $condvar->recv;  # enter main loop...

sub setup_background_command {
    my ( $buffer ) = @_;

    my $job = AnyEvent::Subprocess->new(
        delegates     => [ 'StandardHandles', 'CompletionCondvar' ],
        code          => sub { exec 'unbuffer', 'myscript.pl' }
    );
    my $run = $job->run;
    $run->delegate('stdout')->handle->on_read(
        sub {
            my ( $handle ) = @_;
            my $line = $handle->rbuf;
            chomp $line;
            my $iter = $buffer->get_end_iter();
            $buffer->insert( $iter, $line . "\n" );
            $handle->rbuf = ""; # clear buffer
        }
    );
}

sub set_widget_property {
    my ( $widget, $prop, $value ) = @_;

    my $context = $widget->get_style_context();
    my $cls_name = $prop . '_class';
    $context->add_class( $cls_name );
    my $provider = Gtk3::CssProvider->new();
    my $css = sprintf ".%s {%s: %s;}", $cls_name, $prop, $value;
    $provider->load_from_data( $css );
    $context->add_provider($provider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
}
```

Here, the command to run asynchronously within GTK event loop is the script `myscript.pl`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

#STDOUT->autoflush(1);
sleep 1;
say "data 1";
sleep 1;
say "data 2";
sleep 1;
say "data 3";
```

Notice that the script can be made unbuffered by uncommenting the line with `autoflush(1)`. But in general we must assume that we cannot modify the internals of the command, so I used [`unbuffer`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer) to run the script.