# Gtk3 Hiding a dialog before heavy computation begins (pyGtk)

Tags: python, gtk3, pygtk

My program (pyGtk 3 based) displays a custom built dialog which collects data for a heavy computation task (running least square optimizations).

I'm issuing (in that order):

1. a call for my_dialog.hide()
2. Starting a spinner widget (spinner.start() )
3. Perform the optimization
4. Stopping the spinner
5. Displaying results

What actually happens is that the dialog stays displayed throughout the heavy computational task and only after it is complete, it is being hidden and results are displayed without seeing the spinner.
My guess is that the thread of the dialog is slower than the computational task kicks in.

How can I make sure the dialog closes before the computational task begins without having a performance hit?

(Or am I missing a point here - please enlighten me)

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Gtk3, you are not using Pygtk. Pygtk is Gtk2. Please update your question.

Comment: You need to allow the main loop to regain control. See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52450529/). Or maybe I should say, you need to force Gtk to do it's rendering before you do your main computation.

Comment: Post a minimal example